# how to view folder that start with a "." on windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, android

On my phone I have a folder that is named .Pass I connected my Phone (Galaxy Note 3) to my computer (Desktop Windows 7 64bit) and I wanted to open up the .Pass folder on my computer. However the folder does not show up on the computer, in fact nothing that starts with a . shows up... i'm thinking this is because they are considered blank name files with a file type extension? maybe? Anyway, If someone could tell me how I can make .Pass visible on my computer without renaming .Pass then that would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer, click Organize -> View -> Show hidden files, folders, and drives (a radio button).